# Android - How to fit the graph title in screen

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using the achartengine for displaying the line graph. My graph title is too lengthy. Because of that some text goes beyond the screen. Now I want to fit it in the screen width (Is it possible to set it in more than one line?). I tried But I am not getting. Can anyone help me.

Refer Image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First and the simplest way is to add line break in your title `First line\nSecond line`.

Second way is to modify achart's source. There is `drawString` method in `AbstractChart` class. I don't know is it drawing graph title or not, but it will give you an idea of how it's done.

```
/**
 * Draw a multiple lines string.
 * 
 * @param canvas the canvas to paint to
 * @param text the text to be painted
 * @param x the x value of the area to draw to
 * @param y the y value of the area to draw to
 * @param paint the paint to be used for drawing
 */
protected void drawString(Canvas canvas, String text, float x, float y, Paint paint) {
    String[] lines = text.split("\n");
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    int yOff = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
        canvas.drawText(lines[i], x, y + yOff, paint);
        paint.getTextBounds(lines[i], 0, lines[i].length(), rect);
        yOff = yOff + rect.height() + 5; // space between lines is 5
    }
}
```

You have to determine how many lines you need. We can measure text width with paint's `measureText(String)` method. And then if text width is larger than available width break text in two lines.

```
if (paint.measureText(text) > canvas.getWidth()) {
    ... // Split text in two lines
        // For example you can do following steps
        // 1. Find last position of space with `text.lastIndesOf(' ')`.
        // 2. Then take substring from beginning of text to found last position of space.
        // 3. Try again with `paint.measureText` if substing fits in available width.
        // 4. In case it fits - insert line break instead of space, if not start again from 1. (find location of pre-last space, get substring from start to found location, check if it fits and so on...)
}
```

Comment: How do we know the text is going beyond the screen pro grammatically for putting the line breaks.

Comment: `paint.measureText(text)` gives you width of text. `canvas.getWidth()` gives you width of area where this text will be drawn. If first is greater than second then you know that you need to break this line

Comment: Suppose our text is greater than width then how do we know the exact location for the new line?

Comment: It does this line in example above `yOff = yOff + rect.height() + 5; // space between lines is 5`

Comment: hi i think you miss understand this. i am asking about break point for the new line not space between the line.

Comment: That should be easy too. Find last position of space with `text.lastIndesOf(' ')`. Then take substring from beginning of text to found last position of space. Try again with `paint.measureText` if substing fits in available width. In case it fits - insert line break instead of space, if not find location of pre-last space, get substring from start to found location, check if it fits and so on...